# calling an application from other application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am writing an application in Objective-C whose functionality is to call and execute another application.Pls can i know the procedure???Let me also know where i need to keep the calling application which has to load and execute???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but if all you're trying to do is launch another app, there are a number of ways to do this. The most straightforward is probably by using the [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Here is a simple example of launching iCal from within an Objective-C application using an NSTask.

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/Applications/iCal.app/Contents/MacOS/iCal"];
[task launch];
[task release];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.Now i have referred to NSTask but it is only in Mac OS but the program which i do is with iPhone OS and it does not have NSTask class.Can you please tell me which is the equivalent for iPhone OS?????

Comment: **NEVER** do this example in shipping code. NSTask is intended for launching non-GUI applications. For launching GUI apps, use NSWorkspace or the lower-level Launch Services.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to "launch" another application is if the other application "cooperates" with yours, if you will.

The cooperation comes in the form of a URL protocol scheme that an application exposes. Examples are mailto: (exposed by the system mail application) and sms: (exposed by the Messages app).

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes seems to have a comprehensive list of third party apps exposing a custom protocol scheme that you can make use of.

Launching another app is a matter of calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitterrific://..."];` (for example).

As of OS 3.0 you can also check if a given URL protocol scheme is available via UIApplication's `-canOpenURL:` — checking if some app has registered the protocol scheme, or in other words checking if an application is installed.

If you are writing both apps yourself then launching a custom protocol scheme is pretty simple, however you can't launch an arbitrary iPhone app, and you wouldn't be able to enumerate available apps anyway because of the sandbox.

Comment: Hi i actually want to call a small application(ex: Hello World ) from another application which is not related to third party applications..Let me know the syntax or the method to call the small application???

Comment: Follow kevin.blair's instructions in another answer to register a custom protocol scheme (say helloworld://) in your Hello World application, then use the UIApplication's openURL: method to open that URL (and the app that handles it, Hello World).

Comment: should i import helloworld application in my project or should i specify its path in my code, which is the proper way... also tel me where i'm i supposed to specify the URL in this function?
 -(Bool)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
}

Comment: As I mentioned, kevin.blair's answer describes how one of your apps will register for a helloworld:// scheme, you don't use the app's path because you don't know where it will be installed on the phone, but you do know that opening a helloworld:// URL will launch it, so that's what you do. You "run" or "call" your Hello World application by opening a helloworld:// URL.

Answer (score 0):

See the -launchApplication: method of the NSWorkspace class.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the iPhone SDK also does not have NSWorkspace.

Comment: launchApplication: is not available on the iPhone, sandbox and all.

Comment: Can u please suggest me what will be the equivalent function of launchAppliation in iPhone-OS?????

Comment: Oops, didn't spot that it was a cocoa-touch question, not a cocoa question.

Answer (score 0):

1 Register a custom URL Scheme - In your applications Info.plist specify the subproperties of the CFBundleURLTypes

- CFBundleURLName

  - A string that is the abstract name    for the URL type. To ensure
    uniqueness, it is recommended that
    you specify a reverse-DNS style of
    identifier, for example,
    com.acme.myscheme. The URL-type name 
    provided here is used as a key to a
    localized string in the
    InfoPlist.strings file in a
    language-localized bundle
    subdirectory. The localized string is
    the human-readable name of the URL
    type in a given language.
  - CFBundleURLSchemes

    - An array of URL schemes for URLs    belonging to this URL type. Each
      scheme is a string. URLs belonging to
      a given URL type are characterized by
      their scheme components.

  2 implement the handleOpenURL method to receive the notifications

  (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
      if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"myscheme"]) {
        ...

  3 in the calling application construct a URL to the custom scheme you have defined and open it. The iPhone OS uses this for http, mailto, tel, and sms URL schemes

  NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myscheme://?params..."];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];

Comment: hi kevin,
 My App is calling a Hello World application, tel me wher should i keep that Hello World app, should i import into my project or should i specify the path in URL as URLWithString:/Macintosh/user/xxx/Documents/Hello World?? which is the right way of doing it??